# Removing all html links except specific links PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

I have string that has many links and other hmtl tags, I need to remove all the links from the string except the links that have a specific html data attribute. So example:

```
<p>Some text, <a data-special="special-link" href="link.com">Needs to stay</a> more text <br /> more tags, <a href="link.com">Needs to go</a>
```

I tried this, did not match anything

```
 preg_replace('#<a (?![^>]data-special="special-link") .*?>(.*?)</a>#i', '\1', $result["body_value"]);
```

Comment: Use \\1 Instead of \1

Comment: What about using a [DOM parser](https://ideone.com/qrPWpL)? Note that to keep self-closing `<br />`, you'd need `loadXML` instead of `LoadHtml`, but your input is not valid XHTML because of a missing `</p>`. Is it present, or did you omit it in the question?

Comment: Avoid using preg_replace for HTML tags

Comment: @user5237857 did not work,
-- @ -stribizhev I tried php dom, but for some reason it did not work (will edit the question)

Comment: @VladimirSabo, if you explore some errors which you have got when trying DOM, there is a chance that we can help you to resolve them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for your case: to remove all links from string excepting those which have attribute `data-special="special-link"` use the following approach:

```
$str = '<p><a href="link.com">Needs to go first </a> Some text, <a data-special="special-link" href="link.com">Needs to stay</a> more text <br /> more tags, <a href="link.com">Needs to go</a>';
$res = preg_replace('/<a (?![^>]*data-special="special-link").*?>(.*?)<\/a>/i', '', $str);
```

Comment: This worked, I know I shouldn't use preg_match to parse html but I couldn't do it with DOM, it didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

**It is best practice to use DOM or other HTML parsers to manipulate HTML code.**

Since your input string does not seem to be a valid XHTML, you can use the basic DOM parser to remove the links you do not need:

```
$html = <<<DATA
<p>Some text, <a data-special="special-link" href="link.com">Needs to stay</a> more text <br /> more tags, <a href="link.com">Needs to go</a>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xpath->query('//a');

foreach($links as $link) { 
   if ($link->getAttribute('data-special') == "special-link")
   {
      $newTxtNode = $dom->createTextNode($link->textContent);
      $link->parentNode->replaceChild($newTxtNode, $link);
   }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/qrPWpL)

This will replace `<br />` with `<br>`, but I guess that is OK for this scenario.